# How to know if a user has opened a new Internet Explorer window or tab from the server side

Tags: internet-explorer, web-applications

Short version:  Is there a way to know on the server side (in my case Tomcat, but I think that shouldn't make a difference) if a user request is coming from a new tab or window of an Internet Explorer 8 or higher user?

Long version...

I'm trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413149/persist-a-value-in-an-web-application-without-using-the-session-context).  The proposed answer involves finding out from the server side if a user has opened a new tab or window.  The users of the application are all required to use IE8 or higher, so the answer can be IE specific.

I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850058/is-it-possible-to-detect-if-a-user-has-opened-a-link-in-a-new-tab), which discusses how to know if a page is loaded in a new tab/window on the client side with Javascript.  But I don't see yet how I can make use of that info to solve my problem.  I'm still pondering it.

Later answers to the same post say that it is not possible from the server side.  But that was in 2009, and the answer could have changed since then.  (In this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147027/purposely-re-asking-duplicating-an-old-question) I ask if that is proper behaviour.)